# Show Dialog Box with Mutliple Forms

Tags: .net, windows, winforms

I have a "this application is locked" dialog box on our application, which shows up after n minutes of inactivity and users have to enter a password, or change user, to get back in.

The application consists of 1 or more mdi Parents, with tabbed child forms on each parent. Basically there is a main mdi for the application and each "account" screen that is opened from the main Form opens in a separate mdi parent. The "locked" dialog is shown on the main mdi form.

The problem is that when a user returns to use the app, they may be using a non-main mdi form, and the dialog box isn't visible. Even if they did not leave the app on a child form, they may click on one from the task bar. This confuses the user as the app appears to be hung, but it is jus that the dialog is bound to a form other than the one they are using.

Any suggestions for how to make this a little more user friendly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using `lockForm.Show();`

Using `lockForm.ShowDialog();` instead should give you the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: No, I am using lockform.ShowDialog but somehow it frequently still appears hidden behind another form. This is still an issue and I don't know how to resolve it still.